# Adding quotes to blockquote

Tags: css

I need a blockquote centered in page with double quotes before and after it [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4dyhFZGZMqCQhLVMA6tF?p=preview):

```
<div class="wrapper">      
  <blockquote>
    <p>Quote text</p>
  </blockquote>      
</div>
```

And I have the following CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  text-align: center
}

blockquote {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

blockquote:after, blockquote:before {
  color: @green;
  font-size: 8.0rem;                                      
  line-height: 0.8;

} 

blockquote:after {                                                       
  content: close-quote;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

blockquote:before {                                     
  content: open-quote;
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  text-align: left;                                 
    font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Somehow my quotes are placed before and after blockquote.

I would like the opening one to be on top left position and the closing one to be on bottom right position ...

How can I do this?

**Update:**

Something that looks like this:
[image: blockquote]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/bt1r6psx/

Make blockquote as position: relative and blockquote:after and blockquote:before, position absolute. Then you can position them wherever you want.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">      
  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
  </blockquote>      
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
blockquote {
    position: relative;
    /* background: #ddd; */
}

blockquote:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin-left: -0.6em;
  margin-top: -0.4em;
}
blockquote:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: close-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -0.6em;
  margin-bottom: -0.8em;
}
blockquote p {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Same problem as in Manoj Kumar suggestion. The quotes dissapear when resizing the window. I just forked your code with center aligned: http://jsfiddle.net/t0fndt7k/1/

Comment: Just reforked your fork: http://jsfiddle.net/6mxy7wm2/ (added padding to the wrapper so it helps keeping the quotes visible when window gets resized and on small screens ...

Answer (score 2):

To modify your current implementation, you can use absolute positioning to align them.

1. `position: absolute` to both `:after` and `:before` pesudo-element. Change the left, right and bottom values accordingly.
2. Let `blockquote` have `position: relative` so that the quotes(absolutely positioned) are placed with respect to it.

[**Updated Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/n1eoHPFB9BciipRuK1U5?p=preview)

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
blockquote {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  /* Added */
}
blockquote::after,
blockquote::before {
  color: green;
  font-size: 8rem;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
blockquote::after {
  content: close-quote;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  /* Added */
  position: absolute;
  right: -15%;
  bottom: -60px;
}
blockquote::before {
  content: open-quote;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* Added */
  position: absolute;
  left: -20%;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: left;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  blockquote::after {
    bottom: unset;
    right: 0;
  }
  blockquote::before {
    left: 0;
  }
  blockquote p {
    padding-top: 55px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <blockquote>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </blockquote>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need the quotes to be on left and right .. I just uploaded an image to my question to make it easier to see.

Comment: Code updated. Same method, changed the positioning values.

Comment: Only one problem left: when the window is resized to a smaller size the quotes disappear ... The ideal would be the quotes to be always visible and the text in the center become narrow. I tried to add some padding but it is only applied to text ... And margin I cannot use because it is used to make it center. Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Within media queries, use the alternative code then:http://plnkr.co/edit/ageAzKopvRxBbbMXyEJi?p=preview So when window is resized you can show the block-quotes within the paragraph view-able area.

Comment: But using media queries should not be necessary ... Isn't possible to "get" the area for the quotes so they don't disappear?

Comment: It uses absolute positioning, so you would need to use media queries.

Comment: Check my edit. I have reset the positioning inside media queries. Nothing complicated.

Comment: Positioning gets more complicated if catering to the different quotesets used around the world, as some have quote characters that have large spacing before or after. While you can allow enough space for any of those characters, the larger they are shown, the more space needs to be allowed, leading to excessively large indents required together with an odd-looking whitespace topology. @m4n0's alternate suggestion may be better, which would also reduce the total amount of white space for when there are large amounts of text in the blockquote.

Comment: Note that if an element has a `lang` attribute on an element, without the css specifically specifying the characters to be used rather than `open-quote` et al, Chromium-based browsers will change the characters used depending upon if the locale has a national style guide attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `blockquote` to be `position: relative;`, then set `blockquote:before` and `blockquote:after` to be `position: absolute;`.

Once that's done, you can position them as you like.

Comment: Yes, I tried that even before I created this post: http://plnkr.co/edit/4dyhFZGZMqCQhLVMA6tF?p=preview ... But it seems that has no effect. Am I missing something? I also loose the ability to center the quote ...

Comment: [Here's the updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tX9QudmPhpL9lr1FbrIJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
blockquote {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
blockquote:before {
  color: #ccc;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
blockquote:after {
  color: #ccc;
  content: close-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
blockquote p {
  display: inline;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6o06o12e/)

Comment: Not quite the look I am looking for. I just uploaded an image to my question to make it easier to see.